# jQuery toggle() setInterval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link  href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Geo:regular" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <style>
body {
  font-family: 'Geo', serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  word-spacing: 0em;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function cursorAnimation()
{
  $(".cursor").toggle();
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
  setInterval ( "cursorAnimation()", 1900);
});

</script>
<title>Untitled 2</title>
</head>

<body>

So, what's the deal?<span class="cursor">[WARNING]</span>


</body>
</html>
```

and it works -- technically. However, the toggle is working but it's going WAY too fast. I tried messing with setInterval but it's not doing a dang thing... I just want for it to appear and disappear on loop (like a cursor) but without the fading.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it seems fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/TSJ4K/  changing the 2nd parameter of setInterval changes the speed of the flashing.

Comment: Seems to work just as you want it to (FF4.0.1, Chrome 11 on Win 7)

Comment: Are you sure you have `1900` and not `190`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setInterval( cursorAnimation, 1900 );

Comment: Sorry, not sure then! Does it work like you want it to in jsFiddle? For me it works predictably, firing every 1.9 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

it works as a fiddle just fine, so I wonder what is happening?

i changed it to a fadeToggle() to make it not as 'hard'

```
setInterval(function cursorAnimation() {
$('.cursor').fadeToggle(); }, 1900);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r6C3w/